# JVM Freeze under high load in longevity tests

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, freeze, file-descriptor

Running with JVM:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

OS:

```
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Jvm Options:

```
-Xmx4g -Xms4g -XX:MaxPermSize=4g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -verbose:gc -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

Running in an OSGI environment, Aerospike DB, NETTY (NIO) for networking.

Ran a weekend longevity test.
This was the last print:

```
[2015-12-11 09:54:51,185] INFO  : [GC pause (young)
```

After 2 days I ran strace on the pid, and then those are the next prints:

```
[2015-12-11 09:54:51,185] INFO  : [GC pause (young) 3598M->1458M(4096M), 0.0280020 secs]
[2015-12-13 11:54:54,353] INFO  : [GC pause (young) 3598M->1464M(4096M), 180001.5628870 secs]
```

The first print finished and the next print showed a 2 days GC.

The jvm did not respone to thread dump signals during the freeze (pkill -QUIT pid).
This freeze happens every few days.
The freeze happens not only with the G1 collector, but also with CMS collector.
How can I start debugging this, and what can potentially cause this?

Thank you.

EDIT:
Had another freeze, this time the strace does not release the freeze.
The second freeze was released using jstack.

UPDATE:
Found the problem! Look at the answer below.

Comment: What OS? Have you tried `jstack -m -F`? Have you tried java 8?

Comment: I added the OS type. Did not try Java 8, jstack or perf yet.

Comment: Running jstack released the JVM freeze this time, I will investigate if something in the dump looks wierd.

Comment: Could this be related to file descriptors in any chance? I see a lot of threads BLOCKED on logging operations

Comment: It looks like you have a resource leak and your program is running out of file handles which is preventing anything else from running as it is attempting to log while holding locks other threads need. You should either fix the resource leak or increase the max files and hope this makes the problem rarer.

Comment: Regarding this, I had another freeze, and checked the opened handlers. This time it was only 3600 fds, so I don't think it's related at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem!
It is a kernel bug in `futex_wait()` that was backported to our kernel version.
You can read about it here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64